# How to monitor and list modified files server wide for brief periods of time?

Tags: linux, logging, audit, inotify, last-modified

I would like to, from time to time, enable server-wide file monitoring that will show me all files being modified, updated and created while I have it running and thus simply spewing forth a list of files modified until I hit control-c.

This is specifically for a Linux server (CentOS 6.5).

How can I do this?

Comment: More context, please.

Comment: @ewwhite why is more context needed?  As stated, I am simply wanting to monitor all files that are modified (or created) server-wide.  All files.  There's nothing else to add.  This is for a specific purpose that is not necessary to explain further except that I need this capability.  I want to be able to then grep through the output as needed to filter out the paths that I don't want if any exist, etc.

Comment: More context is always helpful because it may trigger a use case that someone else has already experienced or developed a solution for. It also helps us avoid the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/189200)...

Comment: In this case I am search for all files that various processes modify during certain intervals.  These processes are varied and many.  I am simply needing to find what files they are modifying as some of these processes are storing data in non standard locations as well as keeping logs in non standard locations and I need to understand where these files are and what they are so that I can isolate various issues happening in each of these processes configurations.

Comment: You might want to look at `lsof` then.

Comment: Well `lsof` is not entirely responsive enough to yield the realtime results that I'm hoping to achieve.

Answer (score 4):

[`sysdig`](http://www.sysdig.org/) has turned out to be the solution I've been looking for.

Their [wiki has some exceptionally interesting examples](https://github.com/draios/sysdig/wiki/Sysdig%20Examples#disk-io) for Disk I/O and so much more:

### Disk I/O

- **See the top processes in terms of disk bandwidth usage**

  > sysdig -c topprocs_file
- **List the processes that are using a high number of files**

  > sysdig -c fdcount_by proc.name "fd.type=file"
- **See the top files in terms of read+write bytes**

  > sysdig -c topfiles_bytes
- **Print the top files that apache has been reading from or writing to**

  > sysdig -c topfiles_bytes proc.name=httpd
- **Basic opensnoop: snoop file opens as they occur**

  > sysdig -p "%12user.name %6proc.pid %12proc.name %3fd.num %fd.typechar %fd.name" evt.type=open
- **See the top directories in terms of R+W disk activity**

  > sysdig -c fdbytes_by fd.directory "fd.type=file"
- **See the top files in terms of R+W disk activity in the /tmp directory**

  > sysdig -c fdbytes_by fd.filename "fd.directory=/tmp/"
- **Observe the I/O activity on all the files named 'passwd'**

  > sysdig -A -c echo_fds "fd.filename=passwd"
- **Display I/O activity by FD type**

  > sysdig -c fdbytes_by fd.type

Answer (score 2):

You can check out [iontify-tools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/inotify-tools/).

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about this, but I was hoping for some specific examples towards the goal outlined.

Comment: Server-wide monitoring is not a very common case. So, you might not find specific example related to this. Read the docs and try to figure it out.

Comment: See my solution. `sysdig` works fantastically.